# Converting from cURL to Http request Method in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration, httprequest, curl

Kindly suggest me where I'm I going wrong, It works perfectly fine in cURL but when i try doing in in salesforce I'm facing all these Issues

This is My cURL

```
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer 7512d7f8-2706-4dcd-a288-af482fb728ca" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"filter" :{}}' https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search
```

Equivalent Http method

**My Access Token : 7512d7f8-2706-4dcd-a288-af482fb728ca**

```
public static void new_version(){

        string tok = 'https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(60*1000);        
        req.setEndpoint(tok);

        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('7512d7f8-2706-4dcd-a288-af482fb728ca');
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization' + 'Bearer', authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        system.debug('@@@@@@@'+req);

        Http h = new Http();
        String resp;
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        resp = res.getBody();        
        system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@'+res);

    }
```

Error Which I'm facing

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]
```

Comment: Hi Sharat. In case your problem is not solved yet, I doubt you are doing a 'GET' request in CURL and doing a 'POST' request in code. So I think changin "req.setMethod('POST');" to "GET" should solve you problem.

Comment: ^Above changes along with the authorization changes suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apex is combining Basic Auth and OAuth, you are confusing yourself... that approach won't work. The OAuth dance is NOT the same thing as Basic Authentication.

This is "basic-auth-ish" and won't work with OAuth bearer token. You don't need either of these lines:

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('7512d7f8-2706-4dcd-a288-af482fb728ca');
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
```

... and since your curl script is clearly OAUth, the equivalent Apex header is:

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 7512d7f8-2706-4dcd-a288-af482fb728ca');
```

Make sure to include the space after the word Bearer.
To recap: remove the 2 lines and make sure your 'Authorization' header is as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
req.setHeader('Authorization' + 'Bearer', authorizationHeader);
```

into

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');
```

this will solve your problem. you don't need to convert it again into encoding.

Answer (score 0):

mine solve with following : it might help you.

req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth 7512d7f8-2706-4dcd-a288-af482fb728ca');